# How do we add css + animation in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Here is a little snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
$('#why-red a').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ -webkit-transform: 'scale(1.1)'  }, 'slow');  
    }, function() {
    $(this).animate({ -webkit-transform: 'scale(1)' }, 'slow');
});
```

This could be done with CSS:

```
// image
#effect a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 4;
}
```

and it works. However, in WebKit, on hover, it gets bigger slowly, unlike in Firefox, or IE where the images grow big instantly.

It would be nicer if we could have something like:

```
#why-red a{
    -webkit-transition: .15s linear;
}
```

How can we add transition effects or to scale not just for Webkit, but for IE, Firefox, etc.

**Update**: 
I received a great sample on how to do something like this from a good guy in jQuery  IRC.

```
var rmatrix = /matrix\(\s*([\d.]+)\s*,\s*([\d.]+)\s*,\s*([\d.]+)\s*,\s*([\d.]+)\s*,\s*([\d.]+)\s*,\s*([\d.]+)\)/;

jQuery.support.scaleTransformProp = (function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    return div.style.MozTransform === '' ? 'MozTransform' : 
           div.style.WebkitTransform === '' ? 'WebkitTransform' :
           div.style.OTransform === '' ? 'OTransform' :
           div.style.MsTransform === '' ? 'MsTransform' :
           false;
})();

if (jQuery.support.scaleTransformProp) {

    jQuery.cssHooks['scale'] = {
        get: function(elem, computed, extra) {
            var transform = jQuery.curCSS(elem, jQuery.support.scaleTransformProp),
                m = transform.match(rmatrix);
            return m && parseFloat(m[1]) || 1.0;
        },
        set: function(elem, val) {
            var transform = jQuery.curCSS(elem, jQuery.support.scaleTransformProp);
            if (transform.match(rmatrix)) {
                elem.style[jQuery.support.scaleTransformProp]= transform.replace(rmatrix, function(m, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) {
                    return 'matrix(' + [val, $2, $3, val, $5, $6].join(',') + ')';
                });
            } else {            
            elem.style[jQuery.support.scaleTransformProp]= 'scale(' + val + ')';
            }
        }
    };

    jQuery.fx.step.scale = function(fx) {
        jQuery.cssHooks['scale'].set(fx.elem, fx.now)
    };

}

/*SEMENTARA*/
$('#why-red a').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 
        'scale' : 1.1
        }, 200);    
    }, function() {
    $(this).animate({ 
        'scale': 1
        }, 200);
});
```

For now, this is a good solution, but do any of you have even better ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use jQuery's `.animate()` in conjunction with CSS transforms, at least without a plugin, since the `scale()` part is non-numeric and would confuse it.

However, you don't actually need jQuery at all for the effect you're after. You can combine `-webkit-transform` with `-webkit-transition` (and `-moz` and `-o` equivalents) to animate transforms directly in CSS. For example:

```
#why-red a {
    -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
    -o-transition: all .15s linear;
}

#why-red a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

(See: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/)

If you'd like you may be able to the apply the CSS via jQuery's `.css()` on hover, but this is not needed. Or if you would like to apply css transitions using jquery:

```
$('#why-red a').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1.1)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(1.1)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(1.1)'
});
```

Comment: great, but it seems its far for ie :D.

Comment: @Adam, yeah, there's no CSS option for IE. You can "gracefully degrade" though ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish `.animate()` used transitions automatically when available (and fallback to regular animation otherwise), you should check out "[Enhancing jQuery’s animate function to automatically use CSS3 transitions](http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/09/01/enhancing-jquerys-animate-function-to-automatically-use-css3-transitions/)".

[Github repository](http://github.com/benbarnett/jQuery-Animate-Enhanced) of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

i know this question was asked years ago, but i have found a solution for a similar problem, so i have decided to share.
i have used `@-webkit-keyframes` to create 2 animations. one with `.mouseover` and one with `.mouseout`.
combining with `.addClass` and `.removeClass` I have managed to make this work.

see example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gababa/jxnm27wf/)

or this snippet code:

```js
$('#why-red a').mouseover(function() {
$(this).addClass("scaleAnimation")
.removeClass("downScaleAnimation")
.css("-webkit-transform","scale(1.1)");
})
$('#why-red a').mouseout(function() {
$(this).removeClass("scaleAnimation").
addClass("downScaleAnimation")
.css("-webkit-transform","scale(1)");
})
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes scaleAnim {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);}

}
@-webkit-keyframes downScaleAnim {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1);}

}
.scaleAnimation{
    animation: scaleAnim 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
.downScaleAnimation{
      animation: downScaleAnim 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
#why-red a{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="why-red">
<a href="#">why-red a</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

see the Demos of Jquery having great source.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/

Color Animation 
Class Animation 
Show Hide

Just on the fly..

Answer (score 0):

Another option to those mentioned above is Transit JS.

Using transit js you can call...

```
$('.className').transition({ scale: 1.0, duration: 400 });
```

Transit JS:
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/