# Raphael - Hover Animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

Im trying to have a little animation when you hover over raphael elements.

See Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GVEqf/24/

When you hover over the square it scales up and when you stop hovering it scales down.

The problem is: When you stop hovering over the element while it's still scaling up, it'll start scaling down and it will end up smaller then it was originally.

You can see that when you hover over the element and then immediately move the mouse out of it.

Here are the functions I use for the hovering animations:

```
hoverFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: "...s1.6,1.6"}, 1000, 'bounce');
};
hideFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: "...s0.625,0.625"}, 1000, 'bounce');      
};
```

Comment: Someone already has encountered this problem : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029035/how-do-we-add-css-animation-in-jquery). You should check [this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/) (especially the box4) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would save the transform to a var and transform to the origional state:

```
var canvas = Raphael(document.getElementById("canvas"), 250, 250);

var rect = canvas.rect(1, 1, 50, 50);
rect.attr({'fill': 'black'});

rect.transform("t20, 20");

var origionalForm = rect.transform(); // remember current transform

hoverFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: "...s1.6,1.6"}, 1000, 'bounce');
};
hideFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: origionalForm.toString()}, 1000, 'bounce'); // back to origional state      
};
rect.hover(hoverFunc, hideFunc);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GVEqf/27/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending the transform to all the existing transforms (using “...”) in both animations, you could just reset the absolute transform (in at least one of the animations). This has the downside that you have to repeat the initial translation string but I guess it has the upside of being more explicit.

I’ve modified [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVEqf/25/):

```
hoverFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: "...S1.6,1.6"}, 1000, 'bounce');
};
hideFunc = function() {
    rect.animate({transform: "t20, 20"}, 1000, 'bounce');      
};
```